# React Select multiline labels

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to have a multiline label using react-select or to have two labels for one option?

I pass the the select component options with a value and label

```
value: someValue,
label: "This is my first value - Name: Value 1 \n Foo Bar Date Insert 
Today's Date Here"
```

I've tried inserting a line break, but the text remains on one line in the select input. I'm looking for a solution to have two lines for each option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could keep the `\n` line break and add [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) to the label:

```
.Select-value-label, .Select-option {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tholle, added white-space: pre-wrap to both .Select-value label and .Select-option

Answer (score 3):

Use `\n` as a line break and do the following:

### JSX

Add a `classNamePrefix` so styling react-select elements with classes is possible:

```js
<Select
  options={...}
  classNamePrefix="lp-copy-sel"
  ...
/>
```

### CSS

```css
.lp-copy-sel__option, .lp-copy-sel__single-value{
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
.lp-copy-sel__value-container {
  height:5em;
}
```

### Additional Information

You can add `menuIsOpen` in order to be able to inspect the various elements and their classes.

```js
<Select
  options={...}
  classNamePrefix="lp-copy-sel"
  menuIsOpen
  ...
/>
```